# How to allow users to access a folder, through ".htaccess"?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, octobercms

I created a folder in my domain, called: `SquirrelMail`.

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Black list protected files
##
RewriteRule ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders and files
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.map$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.bmp$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff2$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.flv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp3$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wav$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mpeg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mkv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.rar$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.zip$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Everytime, I go to: `mydomain.com/squirrelmail`, I am getting a `Page Not Found` error.

What should I have in my `.htaccess` in order for me to access my `SquirrelMail` folder?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

> The `.htaccess` is an [octoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) default. I wanted to install SquirrelMail by creating a folder. I do not have access on a sub-domain that is why I did it like that.

Comment: do you have an index.html or index.php in the mydomain.com/squirrelmail/ directory?

And are you trying to get it to look for a index with the: `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`?

Comment: @Tsangares yes i have an index.php in my /squirrelmail/ directory.

Answer (score 2):

October's `.htaccess` file in the stable release uses a newer approach, more friendly to your requirements. See the new white list approach below:

```
##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

Simply add a new line for your folder, that should allow all files through.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/myfolder/.*
```

Comment: this is not working for me